# FFMPEG changing output framerate issues

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to take the input, blend N frames, decimate the other frames and use those for the output with the fps of my choice.

I used this line:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf tmix=frames=15:weights="1",select='not(mod(n\,15))'  -vsync vfr frames/output-%05d.tif
```

That generated images, which I combined into the video. So far, so good.
But I'd like to skip the image output and go straight to video, so I tried this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf tmix=frames=15:weights="1",select='not(mod(n\,15))'  -vsync vfr -r 30 -c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 -vendor apl0 -bits_per_mb 8000 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le output.mov
```

That produces 1.62 fps video, instead of 30 fps.

I'm at a loss on how to get it to output 30fps without the intermediate step of outputting images.

Thanks

Comment: After the select filter, add `setpts=N/30/TB`

Comment: @Gyan that works, but the output video duration is the same as the input video, instead of the new duration ~ times shorter.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Comment: Add `-an`. There is likely a silent audio track in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way to achieve this is to feed the input at the 15-times the desired rate and drop all intermediate frames with `-r 30`:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 450 -i input.mp4 \
  -vf tmix=frames=15:weights="1" \
  -r 30 sandbox/out.mp4
```

However, a `tmix` solution is somewhat inefficient for your use case because it's mixing for all frames, including those dropped. If you don't mind a longer expression, you can try:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 \
  -vf 
    setpts=\'floor(N/15)/(30*TB)\',select=\'mod(n,15)+1\':n=15[v0][v1][v2][v3][v4][v5][v6][v7][v8][v9][v10][v11][v12][v13][v14];\
    [v0][v1][v2][v3][v4][v5][v6][v7][v8][v9][v10][v11][v12][v13][v14]mix=inputs=15:weights=1 \
  -r 30 sandbox/out.mp4
```

[edit] `setpts` expression should be `floor(N/15)/(30*TB)` not `mod(n,15)+1` for 15 successive frames to have the same pts.

Comment: the first command works, but the second one doesn't. It will produce a few (2 to 3) frames and drop the rest.

Comment: Oops, wrong expression for `setpts`. Try the modified version.

Comment: I still have issue running the command, are you sure it's working? there might be a problem with escaping.

Comment: There was one more error. The `setpts` expression should be in the units of timebase (not seconds): `\'floor(N/15)/(30*TB)\'`. If the command is not erring out,  you got the escaping all correct.

Comment: That did the trick. I also had to remove all backslashes. Thanks!